# iOS keyboard presentation issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a bug where the keyboard will occasionally be presented weirdly. I noticed it happen on the simulator but ignored it because I hoped it might just be a simulation issue, but it just happened on my iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1.2.

I have programmed the app in Swift and am using the latest version of Xcode and the iOS SDK.

Any thoughts on a cause?

Below it a screen shot of this weirdness.

[image: Broken keyboard]

Comment: so to elaborate on the issue, the keyboard appears as though the phone were in landscape, floating towards the top of the device? How can you reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am unable to replicate it easily, it is really random.